# Is there any possibility to draw an editable map using OSM data?

Tags: openstreetmap, web-mapping, rendering, overpass-api

I am a newbie on openstreetmap related developments, I need to build a web application using PHP or Python frameworks, that could draw map using OSM data. It should also allows to edit attributes of nodes (ex: highway, signal lights, foot path, parking etc), edited data should not need to be updated to OSM servers.

I couldn't find any proper guide. Let me know if there any guides or tutorials to do so.

Where should I start?

Comment: The answer is yes. However, it is such a broad question, it is likely to be impossible to answer in the scope of this format. I would recommend that you look at some of the examples from OpenLayers or Leaflet to get started.

Comment: I think your approach is not polite to other OSM users/volunteers. If you will improve attribute data of OSM why don't you want to update them on OSM server? What is the reason to have a parallel OSM database, you will lost updates made on the OSM database. Use JOSM or other OSM editor to update OSM data.

Comment: crosspost: https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/47775/is-there-any-possibility-to-draw-an-editable-map-using-osm-data

Comment: @scai My reason to develop a traffic planner. but there is a possibility that user could update wrong data. For this purpose i don't need to update all edited data.

Comment: Do your users only need to edit the tagging of OSM elements, or even the geometry of ways oder position of nodes?

Comment: @stephan75 OSM elements

Comment: Then you need an own database where to store original OSM data, and users can store there modified data. And to modify OSM data you almost need an editor like JOSM, Merkaartor, iD or Level0 all without gemetry features then, in order to display original tagging of an element and edit it by a user. see the OSM wiki about http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Editors

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can also try the service from http://www.map-wizard.com ... (I have no clue whether that website is also dislayed in English language or only in German like in my browser)

They have a platform where multiple users can review and edit the tagging of OSM elements for a certain area from OSM data.

Maybe you can ask them via email about your aim.